# Disable auto import after return in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, auto-import

How to disable auto import when I return in my code

[image]

[image]

As shown in the diagram above，after I choose `re.findall` at row: 20. PyCharm will auto append `"import \ re"` for me，I want to close that but I don`t know the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python auto-import can't be fully disabled in the current version of PyCharm, see [Disable auto import﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#disable-imports). Only the import style and tooltip can be adjusted, see [Automatically add import statements﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#automatically-add-import-statements).

The example in the question with a line break is not typical, one possible reason for this is the file extension being `.config` and not `.py`.

```py
import \
    re
```

What is happening is the line is being wrapped, a combination of several settings can cause this. Go to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Code Style` `>` `Python` `>` `Wrapping and Braces`. If the first option `Hard wrap at:` is set to a high value (e.g 120) then confirm the option in `"From" Import Statements` is `Do not Warp`. See the screenshot:

[image]

One side-effect is that imports might not wrap automatically on longer lines. However, you can always [refactor the code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/refactoring-source-code.html) afterwards.